DynamoDB V2 Enhanced SDK to get only one record matching a partition key

I have a DynamoDB table that has a partition key and a sort key.
In my Java code I need to get one (and only one) record with a partition key if that record exists.
Currently I am using DynamoDB V2 Enhanced SDK and I do this by getting ALL records that match this partition key.
However, if there are lots of records (say, 100,000) with the same partition key, the query could take quite long, when in fact I only need one record and not the rest of queried items (say, 99,999 items) .

import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbTable;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.Key;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.QueryConditional;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.AttributeValue;

private static DynamoDbTable<MyFooEntity> table;

public MyFooEntity getOneItemByPartitionKey(String partitionKey) {
    AttributeValue pk = AttributeValue.builder().s(partitionKey).build();
    Key key = Key.builder().partitionValue(partitionKey).build();
    QueryConditional queryCond = QueryConditional.keyEqualTo(key);
    List<MyFooEntity> fooList = table.query(queryCond).items().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    return fooList.size() > 0 ? fooList.get(0) : null;
}

I tried to limit the query result but it did not work and same amount of records (100,000) would be returned.
List<MyFooEntity> fooList = table.query(r -> r.queryConditional(queryCond).limit(1)).items().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    return resultList;
}

I hope to do a query that, as soon as the first record with the same partition key is found, the result list is returned.

By default Query will try to read all items that match the KeyConditionExpression. Where you have set a limit, it actually limits the page size returned.
You need to set a limit on the iterator, to basically tell it to fetch only 1 page.
table.query(queryCond).items().stream().limit(1).collect(Collectors.toList())


Thanks and that indeed will make the data manipulation on my side faster. You mentioned "By default" dynamoDB query reads all items. Is there a way to make it return as soon as the first match is met?

Perhaps the wrong choice of words. It returns an iterator, in which you decide what to do. Your solution iterated all the pages. Whereas setting limit on the iterator to 1 will get a single page. If you want a single item, set the limit on the Query to 1 and a second limit on the iterator to 1.

here's what I understand: table.query(queryCond) returns PageIterable object, which contains all records in pages. And by having .items().stream().limit(1) we fetch 1 page from all pages. If what I understand is correct, I still fetched all 100,000 records back from DynamoDB and do data manipulation locally. My question: is there a way in Java to get only one matched record from DynamoDB and not the rest of 99,999 records? (Not necessarily using V2 enhanced DynamoDB client). I suppose this will be a lot faster.

No your understanding is incorrect. An iterator is lazily loaded, when you call next() only then does it ask DynamoDB for the page. When you limit both the iterator and the request to 1 you'll only read a single item, and pay for the read of 1 item not 10k.

Now I know what's happening. Your pagination description is correct as DynamoDB only returns a certain size of items each time you call next(). However, table.query(r -> r.queryConditional(queryCond).limit(1)).items().stream().limit(1).collect(Collectors.toList()) does not work as the query time is still way too long (both limits are not taking effect). I found my solution by having an explicit Iterator<Page> object and calling the first next() to get the item.

Following the concept of @Leeroy Hannigan, you can query from DynamoDB and get Iterator<Page<MyFooEntity>> object with 1 item in each page. Then, just get the first item from the first page if it exists. The query performance has improved and query is as fast regardless of how many items matching the partition key.
import java.util.Iterator;

import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbTable;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.Key;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.Page;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.QueryConditional;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.AttributeValue;

private static DynamoDbTable<MyFooEntity> table;

public MyFooEntity getOneItemByPartitionKey(String partitionKey) {
    AttributeValue pk = AttributeValue.builder().s(partitionKey).build();
    Key key = Key.builder().partitionValue(partitionKey).build();
    QueryConditional queryCond = QueryConditional.keyEqualTo(key);
    Iterator<Page<MyFooEntity>> results = table.query(r -> r.queryConditional(queryCond).limit(1)).iterator();
    if (results.hasNext()) {
        Page<MyFooEntity> page = results.next();
        if (!page.items().isEmpty()) {
            return page.items().get(0);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

